# Determine if a set of polynomials is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have to determine whether the polynomials $$p_1(x)= x^2+1\\p_2(x)= x^2+x\\p_3(x)=x+2\\p_4(x)=x^2+3$$ are linearly dependent or independent. 
If the polynomials are linearly dependent I have to reduce the set and find a linearly independent set. I already determined that this set is linearly dependent, now I have to reduce this set to find a linearly independent one, but the problem is I don't know how.

Comment: Note that you could work with the coordinates of these vectors instead of the vectors themselves, if that's easier for you.  For instance, the coordinates of $p_1$ are $(1,0,1)$.  Would you be able to find a linearly independent subset of the coordinate vectors?

Comment: Well polynomials of degree 2 are a vector space of dimension 3, so yes they are linearly dependent.  But you cannot find a linearly independenbt "one" you probably need to find a maximal independent subset.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I think the pronoun antecedence is pretty clear in this case: OP meant "one" to refer to a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the rank of the following matrix as the size of the maximum set of independent polynomials. Also, you can remove the rows by basic matrix operation to find the set.

$$rank\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\right) = 3$$

Therefore, you can remove just one of the polynomials (from 4), as the rank of the matrix is 3. Also, you can express $p_4$ like the following:
$$p_4(x) = \frac{5}{3}p_1(x) + -\frac{2}{3}p_2(x) + \frac{2}{3}p_3(x)$$
So, the set $p_1(x), p_2(x), p_3(x)$ is a maximal independent set.

Comment: @OmG I have taken the permission to slightly modify your last sentence.